# How to justify the coefficients in Bezout's identity can be used to invert a number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I'm getting familiar with solving equations with modulo. After some trial and error and getting help on this website, I've found this method works.

Given the following equation
$$ax \equiv b \pmod{c}$$

1. Establish whether it has a solution
2. Find the GCD between $a,b$ and simplify the equation if needed
3. Rewrite the CGD as $pa + qb$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ as per Bezout's identity
4. Multiply all the terms by the number $p$ found. $p$ is going to be the inverse of $a$ modulo $c$, so the equation will now be $x \equiv pb \pmod{c}$
5. Substitute $pb$ with its modulo from the division by $c$
6. The equation will now be in the form $x\equiv b'\pmod{c}$ and that's the set of the solutions

I am after a formal explanation of why, in step 4, the coefficient of $a$ in Bezout's identity is, in fact, its inverse in set of integers modulo $c$.

Should you find yourself having to write a justification in, say, a test, what would you write?

Comment: $pa+qb=1$ means $pa\equiv1\pmod b$